Routing all traffic (in and out) through wireguard tunnel with port forwarding
I went all over the internet and I couldn't find a working iptables config. I have a wireguard network 10.0.0.0/24 which has 3 nodes the tunnel itself (gateway) 10.0.0.1, Web Node 10.0.0.2, D1 Node 10.0.0.3. and I have tried everything, it just wont work. Also the servers when connecting to outer internet should route everything through the tunnel and tunnel itself needs to on request port 80 forward it to 10.0.0.2. But when actually opening the website in the browser it does nothing. Here are the rules I have already tried on the tunnel:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:443
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

It is kinda hard for me to explain everything so here is an illustration Image of the network. I am honestly not even sure if it is possible.
Ps. All of the machines are on ubuntu 22.04 in different data centers.
EDIT: Connecting straight to ip just decided to start working. Connecting through domain still does not work.
